Why is Animationend firing after a delay with timing function as linear?
I simply want the animationend event to fire as soon as the animation completes visually.
The most similar answer I could find for this was this, but unfortunately using linear in my cases did not solve the issue.


document.querySelector('h1.ani').addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
  console.log("invoked");
});
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  letter-spacing: -500px;
  position: relative;
}

h1.ani {
  animation: morph 4s linear forwards;
}

h1 span {
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

h1 span.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

h1.hide span {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0) translateY(100%);
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes morph {
  0% {
    letter-spacing: -500px;
  }
  40% {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
  }
  60% {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    letter-spacing: -500px;
  }
}
<h1 class="ani">
  <span>W</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <span>D</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>v</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>p</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>r</span>
</h1>




The animationend does fire when the animation completes visually. The problem is simply that the text effect you've defined does not use 100% of the animation duration. Are you looking for animation-delay instead?

It fires exactly when the animation ends - you just don't realize it, due to how you set up your animation. There is little difference between letter-spacing: -5px and letter-spacing: -500px - so it looks like the animation is already finished, quite a while before it actually is.

@MohammedMalleck see CBroe's comment for the explanation of why that is - you're only using 5px of the value you set, so the animation is still updating the other 495px, but visually no change happens because that's far too large a setting

@CBroe ty for the solution it worked..but i am confused on how would i be able to determine what letter-spacing should the container have so that its width becomes 0(i am figuring it out but let me know if you have a simple solution)

nvm seems like em does it pretty fine
